# Onclick background color change and save in database in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql, yii2

I have a row which contains data fields and acknowledge button. If the user will press "acknowledge" button. The result will be change of entire background color of that row and that color will save in database. Now the problem is how should i save the background color of that row in database?

i have tried to use row.addClass('bg-success'); but unfortunately it's not permanent when the page is refreshed.

this is my code for the table row

```
echo '
<tr>
    <td>
        '.$orderdate_call.'
    </td>
    <td>
        '.$getjobid.'
    </td>
    <td>
        '.$thejobname.'
    </td>
    <td>
        '.$thesubapp.'
    </td>
    <td>
        '.$thestatus.'
    </td>
    <td>
        '.$currenttime.'
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="badge '.$bg_css_online2.'">'.$desc_online_text2.'</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="badge '.$bg_css_online.'">'.$desc_online_text.'</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary insertButton"
                        data-jobid="'.$getjobid.'"
                        data-orderdate="'.$orderdate_call.'"
                        data-jobname="'.$thejobname.'"
                        data-subapplication="'.$thesubapp.'"
                        data-jobstatus="'.$thestatus.'"
                        data-currenttime="'.$currenttime.'"
                        data-cyclic="'.$desc_online_text2.'"
                        data-message="'.$desc_online_text.'">
            Acknowledge
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

this is my code for the javascript

```
$('#description-table').on('click', '.insertButton', function() {
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    var row = clickedElement.closest('tr');

    var jobId = clickedElement.data('jobid');
    var orderdate = clickedElement.data('orderdate');
    var jobname = clickedElement.data('jobname');
    var subapplication = clickedElement.data('subapplication');
    var jobstatus = clickedElement.data('jobstatus');
    var currenttime = clickedElement.data('currenttime');
    var cyclic = clickedElement.data('cyclic');
    var message = clickedElement.data('message');

    $.ajax({
        url: '".Url::to(['report/insert-data'])."',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            jobId: jobId,
            orderdate: orderdate,
            jobname: jobname,
            subapplication: subapplication,
            jobstatus: jobstatus,
            currenttime: currenttime,
            cyclic: cyclic,
            message: message,
            '".Yii::$app->request->csrfParam."':'".Yii::$app->request->csrfToken."' 
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Data inserted successfully:', response);
            alert('Data acknowledged');
            row.addClass('bg-success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would expect that when you press the "acknowledge" button, you would have code that sets a status flag in that row of your database to show that it has been acknowledged. When you draw the table, check the status flag and set the appropriate colour. The result of `row.addClass()` is never going to persist across a page refresh because it is refreshing the document in the browser - that disappears and a new document is created when you refresh.

Comment: @droopsnoot so in order to set the color changed when it's clicked, i should make a column on my database which the type is boolean? so for example when the value of the column is TRUE then i set on my code for the acknowledged data on my html page to blue, isn't this right?

Comment: If there are only two possible states for that value, then a boolean column would be fine, yes